# MySQL remove Foreign Key without name

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a script that will remove a foreign key constraint without a set name from several different MySQL DB's.  I have created the following script:

```
SET @CN := (SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM
  information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
  table_name = 'inventory' and referenced_table_name='product_code' and referenced_column_name='shipping_code');

ALTER TABLE inventory DROP FOREIGN KEY @CN;
```

It is correctly getting the contraint name. However it complains about the variable `@CN` in the ALTER TABLE command. Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL is expecting a fixed name there.  So, just use dynamic SQL:

```
set @sql = 'ALTER TABLE inventory DROP FOREIGN KEY @CN';
set @sql = replace(@sql, '@CN', @CN);

prepare alterTable from @sql;
execute alterTable;
```